# Can metamagic feats be applied to (Sp) abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic

For instance, lets say you are a Drow wizard, and you have taken Quicken Spell as a metamagic feat.  You wish to Quicken your innate *darkness* ability, so that you can throw down a cloak of magical darkness quickly as a getaway move without having to burn a spell slot on a Quickened Darkness.

Is this allowed?  Is there some RAW out there that forbids this? Or is this a case that'd mandate a DM ruling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are separate Meta-Spell-like Ability feats, like [Quicken Spell-like Ability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm#quickenSpellLikeAbility) and [Empower Spell-like Ability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm#empowerSpellLikeAbility). Metamagic only applies to spells; you can’t prepare or cast your racial *darkness* from a higher level spell slot to use Quicken Spell anyway.

That said, the proliferation of Meta-X feats in 3.5 is, I think, a mistake. I would support houserules to allow Quicken Spell to also count as Quicken Spell-like Ability, so if you have Quicken Spell, you can also quicken your *darkness* per the Quicken Spell-like Ability feat. There is no reason why someone with both spells and spell-like abilities should have to buy the same feat twice.

Comment: Irrelevant Trivia: DDO (that is based on 3.5) allow you to use metamagics on Spell-like abilities.

Comment: This answer is correct. However, this DM would *not* implement house rules allowing metamagic feats also to be used as the similar feats that modify spell-like abilities. [Monsters with spells *and* spell-like abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/angel.htm) are often sufficiently badass that letting them get double-duty from their metamagic feats seems like just a straight power-up to monsters not really in need of one. (Although, admittedly, I've not playtested such a house rule.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan true enough, but my feeling there is that monsters can be tailored appropriately either way, while I can think of few cases where a player could cause problems and several where these features represent unnecessary taxes.