# Can a bard use Captivating Melody to increase the DC of the Soothing Voice spell-like ability?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, bard

Soothing Voice is a spell-like ability for half-elf bards that give them the ability to expend a bardic music to cast Calm Emotions.

Captivating Melody allows for a bard to expend a bardic music as a swift action to increase the DC of an enchantment or illusion spell.

Can I use Captivating Melody to increase the DC of the spell-like ability Soothing Voice?

Comment: While this exact question hasn't before been asked, a closely related question has been asked and answered [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68480/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Id agree with closing this as duplicate if *Captivating Melody* was a metamagic feat, but its a general feat.

Comment: @ShadowKras I wasn't suggesting that this question be closed as a duplicate but, instead, that the asker may be able to divine the answer to his question from that other question's answers (then, perhaps, self-answer his own question). That is, the situation in this question is *slightly* different from the situation in the other question, but the *answer* to the other question and the *reason behind the answer* to that other question mirror accurate answers to this question. (As you know! `;-)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, you cannot

*Captivating Melody* (Complete Mage, p.40) is a general feat that says:

> As a swift action **before casting a spell**, you can attempt a Perform check (DC 15 + the level of the spell you intend to cast). If you succeed, you can sacrifice one of your daily uses of bardic music to increase the save DC of the next enchantment or illusion spell you cast in the same round by 2. If the Perform check fails, you still lose one daily use of bardic music but gain no benefit.

As you noticed, bard's songs are either *Supernatural* or *Spell-like abilities*, but are **not spells**. On a similar subject that follows the same ruling, you may also not apply metamagic feats to supernatural abilities, as seen in [this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68480/can-metamagic-feats-be-applied-to-sp-abilities). Nor abilities that improve or upgrade spells in general, as seen on [this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93757/do-feats-and-abilities-that-improve-a-spell-work-on-supernatural-abilities).